# Time conversion to IST

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I'm trying to convert date & time stamp to IST using Moment. I tried following
`moment(1369266934311).utcOffset("+05:30").format()` I'm getting output as `2017-12-05T00:00:00+05:30`.

But my required format is `Tue Dec 05 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the date object from the moment object and call its `.toString()` method.

```
moment(1369266934311).utcOffset("+05:30").toDate().toString();
// => "Thu May 23 2013 05:25:34 GMT+0530 (IST)"
```

And, by the way, 1369266934311 is a different date from what you mentioned in your question.